# Settings.refreshAsync is undefined for Word on Mac

Tags: office-js

It seems that `Office.context.document.settings.refreshAsync` is undefined for Word on Mac even though the [API](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/settings.refreshasync) says otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are aware of the issue, and we have a fix in queue, for both Excel and Word on the Mac. We'll update this thread once the fix is deployed.

Comment: Thanks @michael. I'm looking forward to it.

Comment: Do you have an idea of when the fixed will be available for users?

Are we talking days, weeks, or months?

Comment: I don't have visibility into this particular issue, but let m forward this on to someone who does.

Comment: hello jkh, before we answer this question, I would like to know more details about your scenario. What is you plan on using this API?  Can you describe the context or how are you expecting it to work? The reason why I am asking is because maybe this API will not behave the way you expect. Thanks

Comment: Hi @JuanBalmori
I use the document.settings to transfer my add-in settings from the panel to the dialog, since (correct me if I'm wrong) the dialog has its own "browser instance" it does not have the same localstorage or cookies as the panel.

Comment: Thanks jkh, you don't need the refreshAsync method on your scenario, you only need to use the settings.set to create/update a setting  (don't forget to call also settings.saveAsync if you want the settings to be persisted in the document) and settings.get to read it.  The refreshAsync primary purpose was when settings are changed as a result of a changing a setting in a co-auth session and it's a mechanism by which you can retrieve the latest settings, and only works properly in Excel Online.

Comment: That actually sounds right. Do not know why I did not think of that. Thanks @JuanBalmori.

Comment: It seems I still need to use refreshAsync on Windows if my settings dialog is opened through the ribbon I need a way to update the panel with potential changes. Or is there a better way to do that @JuanBalmori?

Comment: i am assuming that you are displaying the dialog using the  Office.context.ui.displayDialog  method for this, right? if so you can subscribe to the DialogEventReceived event when the dialog is closed, and from there first thing you need to do is to get the settings. Then you will get the latest.  Here is a great example of how to use the dialgo and subscribe to the events you need. https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-Dialog-API-Simple-Example/blob/master/SimpleDialogSampleWeb/DialogHelper.js .

Comment: To avoid the complexity of sharing settings between three different instances (panel, ribbon, and dialog) I implementet saving settings on the server and simply loading them with each instance.

Comment: But without `refreshAsync` I do not see a way to communicate between the ribbon (FunctionFile) and the panel in an event-based manner.

Comment: there is no such thing as "sharing settings between three different instances" there is only one settings object and every time you use the API (from anywhere) impacts the same settings object. Again, you DONT need refreshAsync for this. Also no need in your scenario to save settings on the server, this can be totally client side code.  the example that i sent you is precisely doing an event-driven communication between the dialog and your add-in. (you can subscribe to a dialog closed event, please read the sample) and on that handler access the settings that where changed in the dialog.